# How to update dynamically the limits of a range for function evaluation? in python

Tags: python, for-loop, auto-update

I have a function (*Calculations*) with 2 arguments that returns several values. The function is evaluated for all the Phi's (*angle*) in a range and for each **Phi** it needs to be evaluated for **xn**, that can also take any value in a very big range. I'm trying to decrease the amount of **xn's** that need to be evaluated for getting the result I want, because doing it sequentially it takes too much time.

Conceptually I can achieve this based on one of the returns (*delta*) from my function *Calculations*, if **delta** is negative the upper limit of **xn**'s range will be updated to the **xn** I just used to obtain that **delta**, if the resulting **delta** is positive the lower limit should be updated then. This until **delta** is > 10 for example.

I tried to reproduce this idea with this code:

```
# for loop (sequential iteration through curvature values)
Phi = np.arange(0.000015, 0.00004, 0.000001)  # assumed neutral axis depth
for angle in Phi:  # for loop is ok because I want a sequential iteration
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- # 
    lower = 60
    upper = 232
    step = 0.0001
    Neutral_axis_depth = np.arange(lower, upper, step)
    np.random.shuffle(Neutral_axis_depth)
    for xn in Neutral_axis_depth:
        while calculations(angle, xn)[2] > 10:       # calculations(angle, xn)[2] is delta
            if calculations(angle, xn)[2] < 0:
                print(xn)
                upper = xn
            else:
                print(xn)
                lower = x
            continue
```

But it does not work, it updates the upper or lower limit just one time, then fails to pick another random value in *Neutral_axis_depth* to repeat the process.
Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured how to do it, but now there's something else wrong so please answer anyways and feel free to correct this answer:

```
# for loop (sequential iteration through curvature values)
Phi = np.arange(0.000015, 0.00004, 0.000001)  # assumed neutral axis depth
for angle in Phi:  # for loop is ok because I want a sequential iteration
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- # 
    lower = 60
    upper = 232
    step = 0.0001
    while (upper - lower) >= step:
        xn = round(np.random.uniform(lower, upper), 4)
    # xn = random in Neutral_axis_depth
        if abs(calculations(angle, xn)[2]) > 1:
            if calculations(angle, xn)[2] < 0:
                print(xn, angle)
                upper = xn
                print(upper, lower, calculations(angle, xn)[2])
            else:
                print(xn, angle)
                lower = xn
                print(upper, lower, calculations(angle, xn)[2])
    else:
        print('for upper', upper, ' and lower', lower, 'answer is', calculations(angle, xn))
```

and it works, the problem is when is really close to the answer, but not quite, let me explain:

For example, for angle = 0.000015 (the first one it will evaluate) the **xn** that makes `(calculations(angle, xn)[2]) < 1`(the condition I wnat to be satisfied) is around *xn = 73.1998*. The program will pick any number between 60 and 232 and begin to update *lower* and *upper* as intended **BUT**, when it gets between 73.1997 and 73.2, it gets stuck there, the random pick only gets either 73.1997 or 73.2. But that is basically another  question... The update problem is solved though